# Simple Polymer 1.0 data table

Tags: javascript, html, templates, polymer, polymer-1.0

I am trying to create a simple Polymer component that renders a table from an array of data. Example of the intended usage of said component would be the following:

```
<my-table data="{{someArray}}">
  <my-column header="Id"><template>{{item.id}}</template></my-column>
  <my-column header="Name"><template>{{item.name}}</template></my-column>
</my-table>
```

And the render should look like this:

[image]

*However*, upon creating a semi-working prototype, things get complicated. The prototype can be found here: http://jsbin.com/sirutusupu/edit?html,console,output. **Disclaimer**: it doesn't work unless you download it an run it through a local `http-server`.

My **first question**: why does the prototype only work via local `http-server`?

My **second question**: when running locally and when I wrap the custom element with a `dom-bind`, it also stops working. Local code (that is also not working):

```
<template is="dom-bind">
  <my-table>
    <my-column header="Id"><template>{{item.id}}</template></my-column>
    <my-column header="Name"><template>{{item.name}}</template></my-column>
  </my-table>
</template>
```

My **third question**: using functions to format output doesn't work. Consider this extended example:

```
<script>
  function concat(a, b) {
    return a + "-" + b;
  }
</script>
<my-table>
  <my-column header="Id"><template>{{item.id}}</template></my-column>
  <my-column header="Name"><template>{{item.name}}</template></my-column>
  <my-column header="Computed"><template>{{concat(item.id, item.name)}}</template></my-column>
</my-table>
```

The resulting error is `polymer.html:1660 [undefined::_annotatedComputationEffect]: compute method 'concat' not defined`.

Is there a way to get around this without defining Computed bindings? Otherwise the custom formatting of cell values is not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an interesting construction here!

- I don't know why it doesn't work for you in the jsbin, it might have
  something to do with `rawgit`, I used `polygit` instead.
- Formatting will work if you put the computation function on the
  column's `ctor.prototype` after Templatizing.
- `dom.bind` is going to mess up the interior `template`, I would avoid
  it.

This one seems to work:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>My table</title>      
  <base href="//polygit.org/components/">
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html" >     
</head>
<body>
  <my-table>
    <my-column header="Id"><template>{{item.id}}</template></my-column>
    <my-column header="Name"><template>{{item.name}}</template></my-column>
    <my-column header="Computed"><template>{{concat(item.id, item.name)}}</template>
  </my-table>
  
  <dom-module id="my-table">
    <template>
      <table border="1">
        <tr>
          <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{columns}}" as="column">
            <th>{{column.header}}</th>
          </template>
        </tr>
        <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{items}}" as="row">
          <tr>
            <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{columns}}" as="column">
              <td>
                <my-cell column="{{column}}" row="{{row}}"></my-cell>
              </td>
            </template>
          </tr>
        </template>
      </table>
    </template>
  </dom-module>
  
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'my-table',
      ready: function() {
        this.columns = Array.prototype.slice.call(Polymer.dom(this).querySelectorAll('my-column'));
        this.items = [
          {id: 1, name: 'John'},
          {id: 2, name: 'Jane'},
        ];
      }
    });

    Polymer({
      is: 'my-column',
      properties: {
        header: String
      },
      ready: function() {
        this.templatize(Polymer.dom(this).querySelector('template'));
        this.ctor.prototype.concat = function(id, name) {
          return name + '(' + id + ')';
        }
      },
      stampCell: function(row) {
        return this.stamp({item: row});
      },
      behaviors: [Polymer.Templatizer]
    });

    Polymer({
      is: 'my-cell',
      ready: function() {
        Polymer.dom(this).appendChild(this.column.stampCell(this.row).root);
      }
    });
  </script>    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for solving question #1 and #3. Do you have an idea on why #2 does not work, even in your code example? Try to wrap `<my-table>` in `<template is="dom-bind"></template>` and the data binding will somehow stop working. I'm still looking for a way around this. So far, no success...

Comment: If you wrap the table in a dom-bind, the inner templates become part of the `<template is="dom-bind">` super-structure and are not available for use by the column.

Comment: Is there really no way around this?

Comment: There probably is, but I'll have to think about it.

Answer (score 0):

I think one problem you have is the definition of `columns`.  It is OUTSIDE of the `properties` object

It should look like this

```
Polymer({
  is: 'my-table',
  properties: {
    items: Array,
    columns: {
      type: Array,
      value: function(){return [];}
    }

  },
  ready: function() {
    this.columns = Polymer.dom(this).querySelectorAll('my-column');

    this.items = [
      {id: 1, name: 'John'},
      {id: 2, name: 'Jane'},
    ];
  },
});
```

The second issue is the use of `<template>` inside the `<template is="dom-bind">` which is why it stops working.  Not sure why you are doing that.

When you say local http-server how is that configured?.  It is often necessary to make sure that the imports are referencing the right place when then have hrefs like `../polymer/polymer.html`  The tools that Polymer provides (such as polyserve and web-component-tester) all map bower_components is special ways so you can refer to the elements with the `../` style.  Are you using one of their local http-server or something you crafted?  You can do it with other web servers (like apache or ngnix) you just have to realise that you need to change the url mapping to file directory mapping so it works.

EDIT

Right at the bottom of your jsbin you do this

```
  <my-table>
    <my-column header="Id"><template>{{item.id}}</template></my-column>
    <my-column header="Name"><template>{{item.name}}</template></my-column>
  </my-table>
```

However your `<my-table>` element doesn't use the `<content>` tag which is what will pull that content in.  I am not sure its necessary - I thought your top level element template for `<my-table>` already contains the columns.

Comment: When using local `http-server`, the code is identical to that in JSbin. Even the `polymer.html` is included from GitHub. The `<content>` is not needed since I do not need to copy light DOM to shadow DOM.

Comment: re the first point - then I haven't a clue why you can't use it - you are using jsbin aren't you thats different.  re the second point.  I said you didn't need it, but the code I reference has stuff between `<my-table>` and `</my-table>` so where is that ending up.  On the floor, or just floating around in you top level html?

Answer (score 0):

The solution for question #2 (data binding does not work when the component is wrapped by `dom-bind`) is the following. You need to implement the following methods, as defined by the [Templatizer](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/blob/master/src/lib/template/templatizer.html) behaviour:

- `_forwardParentProp: function(prop, value)`
- `_forwardParentPath: function(path, value)`
- `_showHideChildren: function(shouldHide)`

You also need to set the `_instanceProps` to define any instance-related properties.