# Using Polymer.Templatizer and _forwardParentProp method can we achieve lazy binding in polymer

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I am aware that Polymer does not support data binding on dynamically created elements. Is it possible to extend template class to have lazy template and regenerate bindings on the template.

I have created a Plunker for this where data binding is working with in static content as well within dynamic content.

https://plnkr.co/edit/8HD0gNERiFSl7qNKdJc0?p=info

So in code example, instead of x-content can we have something like

```
<template is="dom-lazy" partial="templates/partial1.html">
```

partial1.html

```
<h3>Dynamic Content</h3>
<span>{{fname}}</span>
<paper-input label="First Name 2" value={{fname}}></paper-input>
```

So using Polymer.Templatizer behavior and may be using _forwardParentProp: function(prop, value) is it possible to achieve doz-lazy

Comment: You can only have data binding inside `template` tags, regardless if they are dinamically created or nor. You need to implement the `Templatizer` behavior properly and `stamp()` the template where needed. I have made a somewhat similar [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35343213/simple-polymer-1-0-data-table) regarding dinamic templating and data binding.

Comment: Thanks I will try and update the outcome here

Comment: I tried the my table example. It is good example. However when I made this as editable cell, Two way data binding is not working. I am still struggling to achieve late binding with two way data binding.